# An option is expected here instead of "T" returned upon validating or deploying SuiteApp project using sdfcli command

Tags: netsuite

Upon validating/deploying the SuiteApp project it returned `An option is expected here instead of "T".`

For validating the project used this command `sdfcli validate -authid [AUTH_ID] -p [PATH_TO_SUITE_APP_FOLDER] -applycontentprotection T`

For validating the project used this command `sdfcli deploy -authid [AUTH_ID] -p [PATH_TO_SUITE_APP_FOLDER] -applycontentprotection T`

hiding.xml

```
<preference type="HIDING" defaultAction="UNHIDE">
    <apply action="HIDE">
        <path>~/FileCabinet/SuiteApps/xxx.xxx.xxx/script.js</path>
    </apply>
</preference>
```

locking.xml

```
<preference type="LOCKING" defaultAction="UNLOCK">
    <apply action="LOCK">
        <object>custcontenttype_myobject</object>
    </apply>
</preference>
```

NetSuite Account Release: 2020.2

SDFCLI: 2020.2

JDK: 11

Additional Note: When I ran the command without -applycontentprotection T it deployed to the target account but the file content visible in the target account.

Answer (score 1):

No `T` is necessary; the switch is just `--applycontentprotection` (note the two dashes as well). If the switch is present, Content Protection is applied; if not, it is not applied.

Reference Help - [project validate](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_156049843194.html)

Answer (score 0):

In suitecloud cli for nodeJS you have to provide the flag --applycontentprotection only, the old behaviour has been changed where a user had to provide T or F value.

you can always check the help for suitecloud {command} --help

For applycontentprotection you can check the help: `project:deploy -h`